# Javascript change width of div by a checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Using Checkboxes</title>
<style type="text/css">
.box{
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.red{ background: #ff0000; }
.green{ background: #00ff00; }
.blue{ background: #0000ff; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getCookieValue(a) {
  var b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
  return b ? b.pop() : '';
}

$(document).ready(function(){

var redEl = $('input[value="red"]');
var greenEl = $('input[value="green"]');
var blueEl = $('input[value="blue"]');

if (document.cookie.indexOf('red=') != -1) {
    redEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("red")));
}

if (document.cookie.indexOf('green=') != -1) {
    greenEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("green")));
}

if (document.cookie.indexOf('blue=') != -1) {
    blueEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("blue")));
}

$(".red").toggle(redEl.prop("checked"));
$(".green").toggle(greenEl.prop("checked"));
$(".blue").toggle(blueEl.prop("checked"));

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

    var expiryDate = new Date();
    expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + 1);
    expiryDate = expiryDate.toUTCString();

    if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
        $(".red").toggle(this.checked);
        document.cookie="red=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;           
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){
        $(".green").toggle(this.checked);
        document.cookie="green=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;
        if(this.checked) 
            $(".red").css("width","50%");
        else
            $(".red").css("width","100%");

    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
        $(".blue").toggle(this.checked);
        document.cookie="blue=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red"> red</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="green"> green</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue"> blue</label>
 </div>
 <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
  <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
   <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

What it basically does is that i have 3 divs. the last one works fine and isn't important in this case. 
My Green and red divs are both 50% of width. if green is checked, then red is 50% and if green isn't checked then red is 100%.

my problem is even if green is checked then red supposed to be 50% but its not. red is still 100%. the only way i can make red 50% is by unchecking then checking the green. its like the page doesn't load red: 50% width in the beginning.

i noticed that by reloading the page and in the red div this is writing "style="width: 100%;"" and when i uncheck then check the green its changed to this: style="width: 50%;"

so the source probably needs a change, so it loads width 50% if green is checked. Can you guys pleas have a look into it?

Comment: Mock this up in a fiddle/codepen and get back to us ;)

Comment: hello, i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for flexbox

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xrgdx7xn/) it is for all. But I don't know where is the problem. It seems that all works fine.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't. it won't load the page in the beginning.of course its impossible to se in JSfiddle because its not saving cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `width` in css

```
.red{ 
    background: #ff0000; 
    width: :100%;
}
.green{ 
    background: #00ff00; 
    width: :50%;
}
```

Change

```
if(this.checked) 
    $(".red").css("width","50%");                
else
   $(".red").css("width","100%");
```

to

```
if(this.checked) {
    $(".red").css("width","50%");
    $(".green").css("width","50%");
}                
else{
   $(".red").css("width","100%");  
}
```

**[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zdpwst8L/1/)**

Comment: Hello Uttam. thx for your reply.  i tried yours to. i have a opposite problem now. if green isn't checked when page loads, then red will be only 50%, but if you then check/uncheck green, then the red becomes 100%. so its like no matter what the div won't load the javascript, unless you trigger it by pressing the checkbox.

Comment: So you should change .red{ background: #ff0000; width: :100%;}

Comment: Hi Uttam. its same problem as the other reply. after a page refresh, it doesn't show "style="display: block; width: 50%;"" at the red div tag, therefore it becomes 100%(because thats what it normally is). its like style="display: block; width: 50%;" doesn't load and i dont know what to do. because otherwise your code works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE :` Before you can set the width , you need to check which checkboxes are checked by using `.is(":checked")` and based on that make a determination on what needs to be set at 50% or 100%.

```
    function getCookieValue(a) {
  var b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
  return b ? b.pop() : '';
}

$(document).ready(function(){

var redEl = $('input[value="red"]');
var greenEl = $('input[value="green"]');
var blueEl = $('input[value="blue"]');

if (document.cookie.indexOf('red=') != -1) {
    redEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("red")));
}

if (document.cookie.indexOf('green=') != -1) {
    greenEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("green")));
}

if (document.cookie.indexOf('blue=') != -1) {
    blueEl.prop("checked", $.parseJSON(getCookieValue("blue")));
}

$(".red").toggle(redEl.prop("checked"));
$(".green").toggle(greenEl.prop("checked"));
$(".blue").toggle(blueEl.prop("checked"));

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){    
    var expiryDate = new Date();
    expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + 1);
    expiryDate = expiryDate.toUTCString();

    if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
        $(".red").toggle(this.checked);
        document.cookie="red=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;         
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="green"){   
        $(".green").toggle(this.checked);
        document.cookie="green=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;
    }           
    if($(this).attr("value")=="blue"){
        $(".blue").toggle(this.checked);
        document.cookie="blue=" + this.checked.toString() + "; expires=" + expiryDate;
    }

    if(redEl.is(":checked") && greenEl.is(":checked")) {    
         $(".red").css("width","50%");
         $(".green").css("width","50%"); }
    else if(greenEl.is(":checked"))
           $(".green").css("width","100%");
    else if(redEl.is(":checked"))
           $(".red").css("width","100%");
});
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/nx7ru4y0/2/

Comment: Hey Dino. thanks for trying. i figured out where my problem. its because my red checkbox is always checked. and that makes trouble for me. check this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/nx7ru4y0/1/ and i need my red to be checked ALL the time. so can you think of a solution?

Comment: I have updated the solution to a better approach. please follow the 'update'

Comment: that works fine on the JSfiddle, but then again there is the problem, it doesn't load with a page load. when i reload your example, it says "style="display: block;"" after the red div tag, but it doesn't say that for my source at my localhost. is it because there is something wrong with my page? it doesn't load it.